# How to integrate $\int \frac{4+\sqrt{x^{2}}}{2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \frac{4+\sqrt{x^{2}}}{2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1}dx$$ ? I am trying to evaluate this integral by factorizing $2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1$. Now $2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1=(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)$. Therefore the above integral will become $$\int \frac{4+\sqrt{x^{2}}}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}$$. Now I am integrating this expression by writing $$\int \frac{4}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx$$ $$+$$ $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}}}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx.$$ Now I am facing problem in integrating $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}}}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx.$$ Because $\sqrt{x^{2}}=|x|$. Now $|x|=x(x>0),-x(x<0),0(x=0)$. Therefore we can write $|x|=xsgn(x)$. Therefore we can write the above integral as $$\int \frac{4}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx$$ $$+$$ $$\int\frac{xsgn(x)}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx.$$ But I can't proceed further. Please help me out with this integral.

Comment: Sorry, for the typing mistake. Please forgive me for that. Many people might not have understood.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$J(x)=\int \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}}}{2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1}dx=\int \frac{|x|}{2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1}dx$$
If  $x>0, J(x)=+K(x)$, if $x<0, J(x)=-K(x)$, where $$K(x)=\int \frac{x }{2x^{4}+3x^{2}+1}dx=\int \frac{x}{(2x^2+1)(x^2+1)}=\int \frac{xdx}{(2x^2+1)(x^2+1)}$$$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \left(\frac{dt}{2t+1}-\frac{dt}{t+1}\right), x^2=t.$$
Now you can take from here.

Comment: +1, but the solution for the other OP's integral $\int \frac{4}{(2x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+1)}dx=\int \left(\frac8{2x^{2}+1}-\frac4{x^2+1}\right)dx=\left[4\sqrt 2\arctan(x\sqrt2)-4\arctan x\right],$ is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnneBauval.

Comment: You have to also consider $-x$ @Dharmendra Singh.

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti What do you mean? Doesn't the relation between $J$ and $K$ answer your comment?

Comment: Oh. Yes. I haven't noticed. Sorry @Dharmebdra Singh.

Comment: Thank you @AnneBauval for pointing out my mistake

Comment: But which value to take for $J(x)$ ? I mean among $+K(x)$ and $-K(x)$, which value to take?

Answer (score 1):

When $x\ge 0$ you have
$$\frac{4+x}{2x^4+3x^2+1}=\frac{8+2x}{1+2x^2}-\frac{x+4}{1+x^2}.$$
For $x<0$ you instead get
$$\frac{4-x}{2x^4+3x^2+1}=\frac{8-2x}{1+2x^2}+\frac{x-4}{1+x^2}.$$
You can find these alternate expressions using partial fraction decomposition since
$$2x^4+3x^2+1=(1+x^2)(1+2x^2).$$

Now we know how to integrate anything of the form
$$\frac{ax+b}{cx^2+dx+e}\quad(c\neq 0)$$
but takes a bit of work. This amounts to using combinations of $\ln$, $\arctan$, the power rule, and partial fractions. If the denominator is a linear factor squared, you can apply the power rule. If the denominator has distinct linear factors, use partial fractions. In this case all denominators are irreducible, so you will only need to use $\ln$ and $\arctan$. The idea is to use $\ln$ to take care of the $x$ term in the numerator, and then worry about the constant term. For example, consider
$$\int\frac{8+2x}{1+2x^2}dx.$$
The derivative of $\ln|1+2x^2|$ is $\frac{4x}{1+2x^2}$, so
$$\int\frac{2x}{1+2x^2}dx=\frac12\ln|1+2x^2|.$$
To find $\int\frac{8}{1+2x^2}dx$ you will have to use $\arctan$. Once you get the constants right, you find
$$\int\frac{8}{1+2x^2}dx=4\sqrt 2\arctan(\sqrt 2x).$$
A similar process gives
$$\int\frac{x+4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac12\ln|1+x^2|+4\arctan x.$$

Similarly
$$\int\frac{x-4}{1+x^2}dx=\frac12\ln|1+x^2|-4\arctan x$$
and
$$\int\frac{8-2x}{1+2x^2}dx=-\frac12\ln|1+2x^2|-4\sqrt 2\arctan(\sqrt 2x).$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%294%2BSqrt%5Bx%C2%B2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2Power%5Bx%2C4%5D%2B3x%C2%B2%2B1%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: This is the solution of Wolfram Alpha to this question.